# I have a list of strings and I want to put every string through my code. How would I do that?

Tags: python, arrays, string

So I have a list of strings and I want to put every string through my code. How would I do that?

```
import requests
import json
import threading
import random
import socket
import struct

i = 0

def fg():
  Api = "https://api.mcsrvstat.us/2/"
  f = (List)
  a = (Api + f)
  r = requests.get(a)
  h = r.json()
  print (json.dumps(h, indent = 2))
          
while i <= 10:
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=fg)
    t1.start()
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=fg)
    t2.start()
    t3 = threading.Thread(target=fg)
    t3.start()
    t4 = threading.Thread(target=fg)
    t4.start()
```

and this would be the list of strings and i would like each of them to go through the fg part

```
127.0.1.1
127.0.2.1
127.0.3.1
127.0.4.1
```

and i want it to output

```
https://api.mcsrvstat.us/2/127.0.1.1
https://api.mcsrvstat.us/2/127.0.2.1
https://api.mcsrvstat.us/2/127.0.3.1
https://api.mcsrvstat.us/2/127.0.4.1
```

Comment: I assume that List is a Python list of the IP addresses mentioned in your question. But why are you running 44 threads? Also, *a = (Api + f)* isn't going to help you. Think about it and do some debugging. You'll find it very illuminating

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through within the function and use f strings to format the correct :

```
strings = ["127.0.1.1", "127.0.2.1", "127.0.3.1", "127.0.4.1", ......]
def fg(strings):

  for string in strings:
      Api = f"https://api.mcsrvstat.us/2/{string}"
      r = requests.get(Api)
      h = r.json()
      print (json.dumps(h, indent = 2))
```

Comment: this would work if my list wasnt over 1000 different strings

Comment: sry for not clarifying this

Comment: Assuming the list is predefined, pass it as an argument to the function (check edit).

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve this. Here's one of them:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import requests
import json

IP_ADDRESSES = ['127.0.1.1', '127.0.2.1', '127.0.3.1', '127.0.4.1']

def fg(ip_address):
    url = f'https://api.mcsrvstat.us/2/{ip_address}'
    with requests.Session() as session:
        try:
            (r := session.get(url)).raise_for_status()
            return json.dumps(r.json(), indent=2)
        except Exception as e:
            return e

def main():
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for future in [executor.submit(fg, ip_address) for ip_address in IP_ADDRESSES]:
            print(future.result())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```